# How to replicate a Node.js environment?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a Node.js setup with a number of globally installed tools.

Now I'm moving to a new computer, and want to replicate that environment.

The only option seems to be to list what is in the old environment:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

And then manually install each of them in the new environment.

Is there an easier way to install the same set of global packages on a new computer? Is there a global settings file that I can copy to the new computer to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to install those exact versions but the current versions instead, then you can run this to save the list of modules:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 | sed 's/.* //;s/@.*//' > modules.txt
```

and later use this to install those modules:

```
npm install -g `cat modules.txt`
```

I don't think that there is any easier way than this.

Note that it is not possible to use package.json for modules to be installed globally - it was a requested feature with a reply: ["we're never going to do this."](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2949#issuecomment-11408461) but you can export the list of installed modules to a format similar to package.json with:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 --json
```

Maybe this format can be more convenient for you to parse.

Comment: This looks good. I'm on Windows, so don't have `sed`, but I'll figure out a way...